# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while registering eventbus in onStart Method for 4.4 os version

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

After integrating Event Bus Library its working fine for OS versions 5.0 and above but causing exception for lower versions like 4.4 etc and getting this error,

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at
>   com.tbox.doormanapp.GuestListActivity.onCreate(GuestListActivity.java:53)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBusBuilder at
>   org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.(EventBus.java:48) at
>   com.tbox.doormanapp.GuestListActivity.onCreate(GuestListActivity.java:53)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

They have posted a solution about this on this official site, as 
http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/faq/ 
but this really hard for me to get what they are trying to say as solution.

Here's what they described,

A java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is throw when a subscriber class is registered. What can I do?
First a bit of background to help you understand what’s going on here: Some Android versions seem to have a bug with reflection when calling getDeclaredMethods or getMethods. The exception is thrown if the class has methods with a parameter that is unavailable to the API level of the device. For example, the class PersistableBundle was added in API level 21. Along with the new class some new life cycle methods were introduced in the class Activity having PersistableBundle as a parameter, for example onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState). Now, if you override this method and you try to register this Activity to EventBus on a older device, we have exactly the scenario described to cause to bug. Understanding why this happens will help to resolve the issue easily.

Here are a couple suggestions how to fix the scenario (check in given the order):

Maybe you overwrote a life cycle method with PersistableBundle just by accident. In that case just change to the method without PersistableBundle, for example onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState).

Use EventBus 3 with an subscriber index. This will avoid reflection and thus the problem altogether. As a positive side effect, registering subscribers and thus app startup time will be much faster.

Remove the offending method from your subscriber class. Either pull out the event handler methods into a new subscriber class, or pull out the offending method into a non-subscriber class.

If the offending method is public, make it non-public. This works because of some “plan b” logic EventBus applies: EventBus first calls getDeclaredMethods, which will fail. Next, EventBus will try again using the getMethods (“plan b”). The latter will succeed because getMethods only returns public methods. However, keep in mind that is the least efficient way in terms of performance (2 reflection calls instead of 1 with getMethods considering the entire class hierarchy).

Non of above worked as per mine understanding, they are also some open issues like, 
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/issues/287
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/issues/302
no one is proposing any authentic solution any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: EventBus is working fine for me in android 4.2 and above. some questions to zoom into the problem. Did you face 65k method limit issue? Have you enabled multidex for your app? Have you defined an application class in your app?

Comment: No i didn't faced 65k method limit,
Yes multidex for app is enabled, its working for 5.0 correctly, 
Application class is also defined as per their documentation. No solution yet

Comment: I faced a similar issue. Let me post an answer to the question.

Answer (score 11):

From the comments I think the issue is multidex. This happens because android 5.0 onwards MultiDex can be enabled. For devices and emulators running pre 5.0 os version. Multidex has to be enabled in a different way.

First make your application class extend MultiDexApplication instead of Application:

```
public class MyApplicationClass extends MultiDexApplication....
// use import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;
```

overried attachBaseContext() method in this class and put this code:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(AppController.this);
}
```

put multidex dependency and enable it in app's build.grdle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' //dependencies section
multiDexEnabled true //in default config
```

This solution works perfectly fine on pre and post Lollipop devices.

Comment: This solutions helps me. I had the same problem and this works.